# convert a 15 digit number to hex

Tags: awk, gawk

i need to output a 15 digit numerical input to a comma separated hex string but i cant seem to get it to start at the first character, here is what I have got so far:

```
echo "012345678912345" |awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=""}{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {if (i%1==0) $i=$i ",0x3"}}1'

0,0x31,0x32,0x33,0x34,0x35,0x36,0x37,0x38,0x39,0x31,0x32,0x33,0x34,0x35,0x3

echo 123456789123456 | awk '$1=$1' FS= OFS=",0x3"

1,0x32,0x33,0x34,0x35,0x36,0x37,0x38,0x39,0x31,0x32,0x33,0x34,0x35,0x36
```

how can i make it insert `0x3` at the start or add a random character at the start then strip it out after? the result id want from an input of 012345678912345 would be:

```
0x30,0x31,0x32,0x33,0x34,0x35,0x36,0x37,0x38,0x39,0x31,0x32,0x33,0x34,0x35
```

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -v OFS=",0x3" -v FS="" '$1="0x3"$1'
```

with your example:

```
kent$  echo "012345678912345" |awk -v OFS=",0x3" -v FS="" '$1="0x3"$1'   
0x30,0x31,0x32,0x33,0x34,0x35,0x36,0x37,0x38,0x39,0x31,0x32,0x33,0x34,0x35
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're open to non-`awk` methods (just about *every* platform with `awk` will also have `sed`), try:

```
pax> echo "012345678912345" | sed 's/\(.\)/,0x3\1/g;s/^,//'
0x30,0x31,0x32,0x33,0x34,0x35,0x36,0x37,0x38,0x39,0x31,0x32,0x33,0x34,0x35
```

The `sed` command sequence consists of two parts:

- The first, `s/\(.\)/,0x3\1/g` prefixes every character with the string `,0x3`.
- The second, `s/^,//` gets rid of the first comma.